# Is 2 a zerodivisor in the ring parametrizing rank-n algebras?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $n$ be a natural number; I am studying (commutative) rings $R$ and $R$-algebras $A$ such that $A\cong R^n$ as $R$-modules.  There is a universal such algebra: a ring $R_0$ and a free, rank-$n$ $R_0$-algebra $A_0$, such that if $(R, A)$ is any other such pair, there is a ring homomorphism $R_0\to R$ making $A\cong R\otimes_{R_0} A_0$.

The construction is as follows: Let $R_0$ be the quotient of the polynomial ring

$\mathbb{Z}[\eta^i,\alpha_{ij}^k:i,j,k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}]$

by the ideal generated by elements of the form

$\alpha_{ij}^k-\alpha_{ji}^k$,
$\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^n \alpha_{ij}^m \alpha_{km}^\ell - \sum_{m=1}^n\alpha_{ik}^m \alpha_{jm}^\ell$, and
$\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^n\alpha_{im}^j\eta^m - \delta_i^j$, as $i,j,k,$ and $\ell$ range from $1$ to $n$.

Then $A_0$ is the $R_0$-algebra $R_0[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(1-\sum_m\eta^mx_m, x_ix_j - \sum_m\alpha_{ij}^mx_m)$; the relations ensure that $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is a free $R_0$-basis for $A_0$.

My question is:

> Can 2 be a zerodivisor in $R_0$, for some value of $n$?

For technical reasons, this would turn an ugly, intractable calculation for general rank-$n$ algebras into a nice, tidy one.  Any other information about $R_0$ (is it a domain? how would I tell?) would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, you are looking at commutative algebras, judging from the relation $\alpha_{ij}^k = \alpha_{ji}^k$.

Comment: You're right - I work with commutative rings so much I forget there is another kind... I'll edit to make that explicit. :)

Comment: Could you please make the question in body and title match. (Once it ask zero div once non-zero div. Sure a detail and likel this will not cause major confusion, but it could still be odd if two people answered yes and no, resp, both wanting to say the same thing.)

Comment: @quid: Good point! Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I also think you want to require $n\neq 1$.

Comment: @darij: I don't see why; in that case $R_0=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\eta]/(\alpha\eta-1)$ is the "walking unit" and $2$ is still a nonzerodivisor.

Comment: Ah, by "any" you mean the English "any" rather than the mathematical "any". (Also, nice name you found for $\mathbb Z\left[z,z^{-1}\right]$.)

Comment: @darij: fixed.  It was a side-effect of complying with quid's request above; the "any" in "Is 2 a nonzerodivisor for any n" makes more sense, but when I edited I didn't catch the change due to the ambiguity you mentioned.

Comment: And yes, there are many names for $\mathbb{Z}[z,z^{-1}]$ - the relevant fact is that it represents the functor sending a ring $R$ to the set $R^∗$ of its units, i.e. the set of possible generators for $R$ as an $R$-module.